# Loop Through a List of Maps

Tags: apex, json, map

I am running into an issue where I want to update a student application from a returned JSON payload from a lwc.

1. I am attempting to loop through the list
2. I am attempting to loop through the map and update the student application.

**Error Message**

```
The method does not exist or incorrect signature: void get(String) from the type String
ap.Id = app.get('appId');
```

I have also tried the following
`ap.Id = (String) app.get('appId');`

```
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<TargetX_SRMb__Application__c> updateAllRecords(List<Map<String, Object>> students) {
        List<TargetX_SRMb__Application__c> sample = new List<TargetX_SRMb__Application__c>();
        for(Map<String, Object> application: students){
            for(String app : application.keyset()){
              TargetX_SRMb__Application__c ap = new TargetX_SRMb__Application__c();
                ap.Id = app.get('appId');
                ap.AIS_Medical_Release__c = app.get('medPickListValue');
                sample.add(ap);  
            } 
        }

       update sample;
       return sample;   
    }
```

Comment: I wrote a reply with what I imagine your JSON / Object could look like, if its not working, please update your question with a sample JSON/Object to know how is the structure you send to the method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looping too much, you should remove the second for loop and its corresponding closing `}` and cast get the string out of the object with `String.valueOf()`

```
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<TargetX_SRMb__Application__c> updateAllRecords(List<Map<String, Object>> students) {
        List<TargetX_SRMb__Application__c> sample = new List<TargetX_SRMb__Application__c>();
        for(Map<String, Object> application: students){
            //for(String app : application.keyset()){
                TargetX_SRMb__Application__c ap = new TargetX_SRMb__Application__c();
                  ap.Id = String.valueOf(app.get('appId'));
                  ap.AIS_Medical_Release__c = String.valueOf(app.get('medPickListValue'));
                sample.add(ap);  
            //} 
        }

       update sample;
       return sample;   
    }
```

Comment: Hi, @sergio-alcocer this worked perfectly. I don't know why I was double looping it. Thank you!